# How to sort multidimensional object in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I sort multidimensional object in JavaScript?

My code is so far

```
Object1

Alias:"Device 1"
EventDetail:"{
  "Status": "ACTIVE",
  "Product": {
    "SerialNumber": "ASDFD"
  },
  "Event": {
    "Detail": "Optional."
  },
  "RecommendedAction": {
    "Type": "MONITOR"
  },
  "Time": "1458708988888",
}"
EventReceivedDate:"2016-03-23T05:01:04.07"
SerialNumber:"MXQ436042C"

Object2

Alias:"Device 2"
EventDetail:"{
  "Status": "ACTIVE",
  "Product": {
    "SerialNumber": "ASDFD"
  },
  "Event": {
    "Detail": "Optional."
  },
  "RecommendedAction": {
    "Type": "MONITOR"
  },
  "Time": "1458708999999",
}"
EventReceivedDate:"2016-03-23T05:01:04.07"
SerialNumber:"MXQ436042C"

Object3
Alias:"Device 3"
EventDetail:"{
  "Status": "ACTIVE",
  "Product": {
    "SerialNumber": "ASDFD"
  },
  "Event": {
    "Detail": "Optional."
  },
  "RecommendedAction": {
    "Type": "MONITOR"
  },
  "Time": "1458708922222",
}"
EventReceivedDate:"2016-03-23T05:01:04.07"
SerialNumber:"MXQ436042C"
```

I want to sort above object based on time and get the same result

```
"Time":  1458708922222
"Time":  1458708988888
"Time":  1458708999999
```

Result would be something like that

```
Object3

Alias:"Device 3"
EventDetail:"{
  "Status": "ACTIVE",
  "Product": {
    "SerialNumber": "ASDFD"
  },
  "Event": {
    "Detail": "Optional."
  },
  "RecommendedAction": {
    "Type": "MONITOR"
  },
  "Time": "1458708922222",
}"
EventReceivedDate:"2016-03-23T05:01:04.07"
SerialNumber:"MXQ436042C"

Object1

Alias:"Device 1"
EventDetail:"{
  "Status": "ACTIVE",
  "Product": {
    "SerialNumber": "ASDFD"
  },
  "Event": {
    "Detail": "Optional."
  },
  "RecommendedAction": {
    "Type": "MONITOR"
  },
  "Time": "1458708988888",
}"
EventReceivedDate:"2016-03-23T05:01:04.07"
SerialNumber:"MXQ436042C"

Object2

Alias:"Device 2"
EventDetail:"{
  "Status": "ACTIVE",
  "Product": {
    "SerialNumber": "ASDFD"
  },
  "Event": {
    "Detail": "Optional."
  },
  "RecommendedAction": {
    "Type": "MONITOR"
  },
  "Time": "1458708999999",
}"
EventReceivedDate:"2016-03-23T05:01:04.07"
SerialNumber:"MXQ436042C"
```

Comment: You can't sort an object.

Comment: _"My code is so far..."_, what code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the objects into an array and apply a sorting.

```
var objects= [Object1, Object2, Object3];
objects.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.EventDetail.Time - b.EventDetail.Time;
});
```

Comment: I want array to be sort in reverse order

Comment: change the return to `return b.EventDetail.Time - a.EventDetail.Time;` for reverse ordering.

Answer (score 0):

try storing the objects in an array and using the Array.sort() method. Your comparison function would compare the EventDetail.Time value of each element.

Answer (score 0):

@NinaScholz answer is good but `EventDetail.Time` is in string format. Before directly comparing both, try to convert that to integer for better results.

Because `"2"` is greater then `"12"` however `2` is less then `12`.

```js
var objects = [{
    Alias: "Device 1",
    EventDetail: {
        "Status": "ACTIVE",
        "Product": {
            "SerialNumber": "ASDFD"
        },
        "Event": {
            "Detail": "Optional."
        },
        "RecommendedAction": {
            "Type": "MONITOR"
        },
        "Time": "1458708988888",
    },
    EventReceivedDate: "2016-03-23T05:01:04.07",
    SerialNumber: "MXQ436042C"
  },
  {
    Alias: "Device 2",
    EventDetail: {
        "Status": "ACTIVE",
        "Product": {
            "SerialNumber": "ASDFD"
        },
        "Event": {
            "Detail": "Optional."
        },
        "RecommendedAction": {
            "Type": "MONITOR"
        },
        "Time": "1458708999999",
    },
    EventReceivedDate: "2016-03-23T05:01:04.07",
    SerialNumber: "MXQ436042C"
}];



function sortByTime(obj) {
    return obj.sort(function(x, y) {
        return parseInt(y.EventDetail.Time) - parseInt(x.EventDetail.Time);
    });
}

var sorted = sortByTime(objects)
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(sorted, 0, 2) + '</pre>')
```

Comment: I want array to be sort in reverse order